# Checkboxes are not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dojo

The check-box code below is not working for creating check-boxes against each and every folder of tree structure. It is simple java-script and HTML concept of check boxes which I made use of. I want check-boxes to be created for the tree structure against each and every folder(in left hand side ) of the tree hierarchy.

As the moment I am getting the output as a text associated with each and every folder of the tree hierarchy. So is it something I am doing wrong here? If so, kindly suggest me how can I rectify this error.

```
var tree = new Tree({
                model: model,
                checkBoxes: true,
                persist: false,
                branchIcons: true,
                branchReadOnly: false,
                checkBoxes: true,
               nodeIcons: true,
               getLabel: function(item) {
               if (!item.root)
               return '<input type="checkbox" name="'+ item.name +'" id="'+ item.name +'" value="1" /> '+ item.name;
                                 }                  
            }, "tree");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding HTML in a dojo Tree label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494575/adding-html-in-a-dojo-tree-label)

Comment: here my query was to add checkboxes for a tree issue as my above code is not working, it is displaying only texts instead of checkboxes. But the link you shared has some other html labels to be added. Can you please suggest how can i do that for checkboxes?

Comment: Thanks for the reply I completed the check-box stuff by creating a new instance of cb from dijit check-box tree.